# Project Server 2010 - Exchange Server 2010 Integration Architecture

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-project

Is there anybody know how this integration works. There are some docs about how to configure Project Server 2010 to work with Exchange Server 2010 ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468700.aspx ) but I don't understand how it works.

I'm looking for integration architecture, which server uses which web service and when ?

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Project Server 2010, is not anymore standalone product, it must be installed on Microsoft Office Sharepoint 2010.
After this, you will have web site working, with accessing projects, tasks etc, and you can connect Microsoft Office Project to it.
However, after this, you can setup Sharepoint to talk to Exchange and send emails, notifications etc.